# Splunk Python Connection Lost

Tags: python, splunk

I'm using python to execute a splunk search query and return the results. I connect with the following string:

```
service = client.connect(
    host=HOST,
    port=PORT,
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD
)
```

The variables have been tested to work, and it connects to splunk, but sometimes, when I run these lines of code:

```
print "Installed App Names \n"
for app in service.apps:
    print app.name
```

It returns this error:

```
Request Failed: Session is not logged in
```

About 50% of the time, the code works, and it executes. Is this inconsistency in code results do to the `service =` lines of code not actually connecting to the splunk server? Can these connections time out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect` can take an `autologin=True` argument to allow the bindings to try to re-connect when authentication fails, instead of raising that error immediately.

Comment: So that line of code would look like the following: `service = client.connect(
    host=HOST,
    port=PORT,
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD,
    autologin=True)`?

Comment: I'm trying to execute a few hundred splunk queries in one python script and somewhere within the script I get the following error: `splunklib.binding.AuthenticationError: Autologin succeeded, but there was an auth 
error on next request. Something is very wrong.` because it's such a long script to execute and I loose connection during that time. Is there anyway to ensure I won't loose connection from Splunk?

Comment: That is a new one for me, sorry. Even if you lose connection during that time, with autologin setup, when authentication fails it will try to re-login (once per request) and repeat the request.  What that error is telling you is that it *did* try to re-login, and it succeeded, but authentication still failed.  I am not sure why in your case.  Are you sure your user has permission to do whichever action fails? Maybe Splunk's internal logs can shed some light.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would authorize me the first time but not the second. I'll dive in and see why

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should get the token and session id of splunk using your python code. Please find the below code if this could help you.

```
import json,os,sys,requests
BASE_URL = "https://SPLUNKLB / SPLUNK WEB URL"

def getToken():
# body for token request
payload = {'username': "",'password': ""}
TOKEN_URL = "/services/auth/login?output_mode=json"
# post token request
res = requests.post(BASE_URL+TOKEN_URL, data=payload, verify=False)
if (res.status_code == 200):
# Get token out of response
resJson = json.loads(res.content)
return resJson.get('sessionKey')
else:
print res.status_code, res.content
```